# "A plastic washing tub" or "A plastic basin"?

Tags: phrase-request, image-identification

I got the large round container without a lid, used for washing clothes in the below picture. But I don't know how to call it.

> **What do you name that plastic washing container?** 
>   A plastic washing tub, a plastic basin or something?

[image: Washing tub or Basin]

Comment: If you google **plastic basin**, you will see numerous identical images. **Plastic tub** throws up similar images, although the tubs tend to be deeper than the basins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where I come from, this is a plastic basin or bowl - it is round, has no lid, and can't be described as a box.

A plastic tub is perhaps a slightly more generic term, applying to pretty much any kind of plastic box, but particularly one with a lid.

Answer (score 1):

I (UK) call this a "washing up bowl"

[Amazon shopping list](https://www.amazon.co.uk/slp/plastic-washing-up-bowl/egut4xjtoe963xv)